# Scale down a larger number from 0 - 1 - 0

Tags: range, scaling, normalize, gml

I'm not math savvy - but what I want to do seems to be math heavy.

I'm looking to scale down a number which ranges from 0-800 so that it is within a range of 0-1-0 (so 1 being 400). Not sure if this is possible, but my attempts at a solution have not been fruitful. Any indication as to where to look for a solution would be of great benefit!

It's so I can change the alpha of images depending on the screen location - the centre-most images should be 100% visible, whilst as it get's further to the edge of the screen, the images should become more transparent. The range for alpha is 0-1.

Kind regards, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the graph of `1-abs(1-2x/a)` where `a=800`:

[image: 1-abs(1-2x/a)]

Here is `sin(pi*x/a)`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer and solved my problem! Will not forget the power of sin and abs :)

Comment: @cider you can also vary the results by raising any of the functions to some positive power, e.g. `(sin(pi*x/a))^2` or `(sin(pi*x/a))^0.5`

Comment: Thanks - that was another aspect I needed to work out! :)